# How to use return function in recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I am having this below code for inorder traversal of tree:

```
void inOrder(struct node* r)
{
    if (r==NULL)
    return;

    else
    {
        inOrder(r->left);
        printf("%d ", r->value);
        inOrder(r->right);
    }
}
```

I am having this silly doubt:

When the bottom most left child is passed as root, it is not null. 
In the next iteration root will be null (as left child of bottom most left child will be null) and it will encounter return.

Wont this return statement pass the control to main function (or wherever it is called) without printing anything?

Does return behave differently in recursion?

Comment: Do you know what a function call stack is?

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't think a notion of call stack is required to understand this, just the basic semantics of function calls and the return statement

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like all other functions. I think you might be thinking of recursion as a kind of loop, but it's a normal function call.

Comment: @PasserBy - Clearly it is required. Otherwise the OP would have been unlikely to get confused about where the return statement takes them.

Comment: @StoryTeller the call stack is for all intents and purposes, an implementation detail, albeit a very well-known one. A function call and return statement is a concept. For example, explaining function calls in Haskell with a call stack doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PasserBy - A call stack, for all intents an purposes, is how one visualizes recursive calls. Even when tracing them on paper, the diagram naturally has LIFO semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `return` will pass the control back to the position where the current "layer" of function is called.

Function calls are organized in a structure called stack. Imagine that there is a box in your computer. The computer can put an element into the box(on top the other elements in the box), or it can remove the element at the top of the box. Consider the following code.

```
void f(int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return;
    f(x - 1);
}
```

If you call `f(2)` in the main function, the computer puts `f(2)` into the box. When `f(2)` is executed, it calls `f(1)` inside the function, so the computer puts `f(1)` into the box(on top of `f(2)`). As `f(1)` also calls `f(0)`, the computer puts `f(0)` into the box.

When `f(0)` is executed, nothing is called and it meets the `return` instruction. So the computer removes `f(0)` from the box, and `f(1)` is now on top of the box. So your computer knows that it is `f(1)` rather than `main` that calls `f(0)`, so it will continue executing `f(1)`. It is the same when `f(1)` is returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation. It makes things very clear. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> When the bottom most left child is passed as root, it is not null.

```
void inOrder(struct node* r)
 {
if (r==NULL)
return;

else{
inOrder(r->left);
printf("%d ", r->value);
inOrder(r->right);
}

}
```

In your above code when you pass the bottom most left child as root.

It first executes this line

```
if (r==NULL) return;
```

as `r` is not null currently it will skip this return.

In the else part it would now execute

```
else{
  inOrder(r->left);
```

Here, It is calling the same function again so, the current execution will pause for a moment and resume when this call returns.

Now, `inOrder(r->left);` call `inOrder(struct node* r);` again with `null` as parameter `r` to this call. since, you are passing  `r->left` which is null.

so, this call to `inorder` will hit `return`

```
if (r==NULL) return;
```

As it returns it will resume last instance of `inorder` call  which paused at
`inOrder(r->left);` call.

> This is possible because whenever you call a function from inside a
>   function is maintains a [call stack.](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html)

Now, after resuming it will execute the next line

`printf("%d ", r->value);`

Which will print the value in your bottom left most node.

finally, it will call the last line

`inOrder(r->right);` which will again pause the execution of current function and after saving the current state of function in call stack it will call the `inorder` with null again `r->right` which will return again from

`if (r==NULL) return;`

and finally it will come back to original execution of `inorder` and resume and as there are no instruction left it will return to the `main` method if you called from there and resume what left in main.

so, your answer is it will print only the value in the bottom most left node.

Answer (score 0):

A classical example of recursion might better illustrate the problem

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

If we were to call `factorial(3)`, it will recursively call `factorial` till the base case `n == 0`, at which point, will return the control flow to the point where it was called, *which is `factorial(1)` and not `main`.*

So, no, your return statement goes back to the parent node where the function was called.